# Fast way of iterate over trues in boolean array

Tags: java, arrays, performance, boolean

I have a big array of booleans and i need just to work with the true elements, and need theyer index.

```
for (int x = 0; x < cells.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < cells[0].length; y++) {

                if (cells[x][y]) {
                    g.fillRect(x * cellSize, y * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
                }

        }
    }
```

so how can i do that without the two foor loops and save the time?

Comment: I suspect you can't. If you want to iterate over 2D array you need either two loops (one iterating over rows, other over columns) or one loop which will iterate x*y (assuming those lengths are fixed) times, but then you will also need to spend some time on calculations which will tell you which row and column you are visiting. Maybe create other structure, which will only hold points which should be used, instead of also holding positions which are "false".

Comment: Is it possible that you can change your cells 2d array to some other structure to hold only true values?

Comment: @Sunil Singhal The problem is more that when i produce a nother structure with 40000*40000 entries its normally pretty slow...

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this is the best you can get.

You are already using a primitive array and I expect primitive boolean type.

The only thing I could suggest is saving `cells.length` and `cells[0].length` in `final` variables before the loops, it could save some time, but the compiler may already optimize this on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, due to your requirements you are stuck in *`O(n)`*...  Meaning, you will have to observe each value in the array once to locate all `cells` that have a `true` value

Answer (score 0):

You can implement some **array wrapper** which will link `true` values (in cost of set operation) so that you will be able to iterate only `true` indices.

Comment: The problem is that wrapper mostly are slower in initialisation. And that is a problem two

Answer (score -1):

We can do by this, Convert int[array] to String and find index where 1 present. Based on index perform the operation.

```
String arrayStr=Arrays.toString(cells[0].length);

String booleanVal="1";
int index = word.indexOf(booleanVal);

    while(index >= 0) {

                if (cells[x][index]) {
                    g.fillRect(x * cellSize, index * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
                }

    index = word.indexOf(arrayStr, index+1);
}
```

Comment: sounds interesting i will try that out but i think it depents on the implementation of indexOf if thats realy faster.

Comment: looked for it and indexOf works in O(n) in this case so that is much slower than just use two for loops ...

Comment: If for inner for loop order is not important, Means sequence. y=0,1,2,3,...etc   Then we start from middle and we go LEFT <- center -> Right with ODD(1) value Jump and EVEN value Jump.   Eg. y(max) =30 ...  Then will start from 15.         ... 13,14,15,16,17,...

Comment: that makes no difference.

Answer (score -1):

By this your inner for loop with run n/4 times. It save time..

Pass a integer value for |cells[0].length/2|.

/*********************
*/

```
for (int y=0, oddOccurLeft = cells[0].length/2,oddOccurRight = cells[0].length/2, evenOccurLeft=cells[0].length/2,evenOccurRight=cells[0].length/2; ;y++ ) {

    if (cells[x][oddOccurLeft]) {
                    g.fillRect(x * cellSize, oddOccurLeft * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
    }

    if (cells[x][oddOccurRight]) {
                    g.fillRect(x * cellSize, oddOccurRight * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
    }

    if (cells[x][evenOccurLeft]) {
                    g.fillRect(x * cellSize, evenOccurLeft * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
    }

    if (cells[x][evenOccurRight]) {
                    g.fillRect(x * cellSize, evenOccurRight * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
    }

    ***if(oddOccurLeft<0 && oddOccurRight<0 && oddOccurRight>cells[0].length && evenOccurLeft>cells[0].length && evenOccurRight>cells[0].length)
        break;***

    oddOccurLeft=oddOccurLeft-y*2+1;
    oddOccurRight=oddOccurRight+y*2+1;

    evenOccurLeft=evenOccurLeft-y*2;
    evenOccurRight=evenOccurRight+y*2;

   }
```